# strpos not working to check if a string is not inside a string (PHP)

Tags: php

Here's my piece of code:

```
$response = "";
foreach ($filtro as $key => $value) {
    $nomeCidade = getResults("SELECT nome FROM tbl_cidades WHERE id = '".$key."'")[0]["nome"];
    if (strpos($response, $nomeCidade) === false) {
        $response .= '<optgroup label="'.$nomeCidade.'">';
    }
    var_dump($response);
}
```

var_dump outputs:

```
string(42) "<optgroup label="São José do Rio Preto">"
string(69) "<optgroup label="São José do Rio Preto"><optgroup label="Sorocaba">"
string(105) "<optgroup label="São José do Rio Preto"><optgroup label="Sorocaba"><optgroup label="Salto de Pirapora">"
```

There's 3 occurences of "São José do Rio Preto", and that wasn't supposed to happen, since I check if the string is not inside `$response` before adding a new city name. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the value of `$response` within your loop. Since you are concatining the next option to the previous option, the response you are seeing is correct.

I suspect that you intend to check the response after the loop instead of within it.